# Oracle SQL query with multiple columns using same subquery with OR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need help in simplifying the below Oracle SQL query with OR condition:
is it possible to using one single select query instead of multiple.

for this sub query "select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd'" i was able to make it into single instead of writing 4 times as it is just giving one value. but for the second sub query it is writing multiple values so i am not able to combine them.

```
select * from catalog  where 
(
(select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd') in (approver_user,CERTIFIER_USER,FULFILLMENT_USER) 
or ('abcd') in (EMERGENCYAPPROVERUSER,SPECIALAPPROVERUSER)
or approver_role IN 
(select ugp.ugp_key from ugp , usg,usr uuu where ugp.ugp_key=usg.ugp_key and usg.usr_key=uuu.usr_key  and uuu.usr_login='abcd')
or CERTIFIER_ROLE IN 
(select ugp.ugp_key from ugp , usg,usr uuu where ugp.ugp_key=usg.ugp_key and usg.usr_key=uuu.usr_key  and uuu.usr_login='abcd')
or FULFILLMENT_ROLE IN 
(select ugp.ugp_key from ugp , usg,usr uuu where ugp.ugp_key=usg.ugp_key and usg.usr_key=uuu.usr_key  and uuu.usr_login='abcd')
)
and entity_type='Entitlement';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WITH clause

```
WITH some_query AS(
    select ugp.ugp_key from ugp , usg,usr uuu 
    where ugp.ugp_key=usg.ugp_key and usg.usr_key=uuu.usr_key  and uuu.usr_login='abcd'
)
select * from catalog  
where 
(
    (select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd') in (approver_user,CERTIFIER_USER,FULFILLMENT_USER) 
    or 
    ('abcd') in (EMERGENCYAPPROVERUSER,SPECIALAPPROVERUSER)
    or 
    approver_role IN    (SELECT * FROM some_query)
    or 
    CERTIFIER_ROLE IN   (SELECT * FROM some_query)
    or 
    FULFILLMENT_ROLE IN (SELECT * FROM some_query)
)
and entity_type='Entitlement';
```